# I can't use javascript variable in other variable

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jsp, jstl

I want to make dynamic dropdown, but it doesn't work. How to make this work ?

Data Type of citiesMap

```
Map<String,List<String>>
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <label>Province</label>
    <div>
        <c:set var="provinces" id="provinces" value="${provinces}"/>
        <form:select path="province" id="province">
            <form:options items="${provinces}"  />
        </form:select>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label>City</label>
    <div>
        <c:set var="cities" id="cities" value="${citiesMap['']}"/>
        <form:select path="city" id="city">
            <form:options items="${cities}"  />
        </form:select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javacript:

```
function changeProv(){
        var province = document.getElementById('province').value;
        document.getElementById("cities").value = '${citiesMap[province]}';
};
```

I expect the output is list of the cities from the province chosen. But the output is `'Cannot set property 'value' of null'`

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong but it looks like you are trying to use template literals but not using backticks?

eg. `document.getElementById("cities").value = '${citiesMap[province]}';`
should be:

```
document.getElementById("cities").value = `${citiesMap[province]}`;
```

Not sure if that applies to your app as I don't recognise the markup.